# I cannot change the font size on LaTeXIt

Tags: formatting

I am using LatexIt an editor that allows the user to write LaTeX equations on Microsoft Presentation.

I am having a very hard time using this application as everytime I write something and try to crop it and project it onto the Microsoft presentation, my image just enlarges for no reason.

Here is an example

http://prntscr.com/ckvmv3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this in your LaTeXiT preferences:

[image: screenshot]

Add any globally-effective commands you'd like there – but keep in mind they should be valid for use in the preamble!

Comment: Thanks but this question is obsolete now. I just found out you can use LateX to make presentations...

Comment: @jacobsmith yeah, beamer!